# Thread with highest priority(255) running too much time on QNX 7.1

Tags: c++, multithreading, qnx, thread-priority

We have a thread (named **Patie#ty_2TimTh** in the below attachment) with **priority 255** running on **QNX 7.1**. The host is **X86** with **12 CPU Core**. This thread affinity is set to **CPU 7/8/9**, and the maximum CPU partition is 20% (less than 3/12=25%). This thread loops forever to receive pulse event and post **semaphore** to notify work thread. The looping pseudo code lists below:

```
while (true) {
    MsgReceivePulse();
    ret = sem_getvalue(sem, value);
    if (!((0 == ret) && (value > 0))) {
        sem_post(sem); // post only value <= 0
    }
}
```

The running time of the above code is about **10us**. But we found the running time was nearly **3ms** sometimes, when we used QNX **tracelogger** to catch some events. See the attachment.

[image]

This thread's events list below:

```
Event,  Time,        Cycle,       CPU, Owner,                Class,       Type,   Data
696441, 613ms 438us, 0x265209E82, 7, safety Patie#ty_2TimTh, Process and Thread, Running, policy_name FIFO pid 9424945 tid 34 priority 255 policy 1 partition 7 sched_flags 0
696442, 613ms 438us, 0x26520A3C0, 7, safety Patie#ty_2TimTh, Communication, Receive Pulse, scoid 0x10005 pid 9424945 process safety
696443, 613ms 438us, 0x26520A4FA, 7, safety Patie#ty_2TimTh, Kernel Calls, MsgReceivePulsev (64) Exit, rcvid 0x0 rmsg0 0x0 rmsg1 0x0 rmsg2 0x0 info->nd 0 info->srcnd 0 info->pid 0 info->tid 0 info->chid 0 info->scoid 0 info->msglen 0 info->srcmsglen 0 info->dstmsglen 0 info->priority 0 info->flags 0 info->reserved 0
696885, 613ms 762us, 0x265306EF0, 7, safety Patie#ty_2TimTh, System, IPI (64), ipicmd 0x20 CHECK_INTR ipi 0x257f781317 tid 34 pid 9424945 process safety
696903, 613ms 777us, 0x2653128D0, 7, safety Patie#ty_2TimTh, Process and Thread, Running, policy_name FIFO pid 9424945 tid 34 priority 255 policy 1 partition 7 sched_flags 0
698114, 614ms 762us, 0x265612411, 7, safety Patie#ty_2TimTh, System, IPI (64), ipicmd 0x20 CHECK_INTR ipi 0x257f781317 tid 34 pid 9424945 process safety
698134, 614ms 781us, 0x265620D94, 7, safety Patie#ty_2TimTh, Process and Thread, Running, policy_name FIFO pid 9424945 tid 34 priority 255 policy 1 partition 7 sched_flags 0
698691, 615ms 181us, 0x26575868B, 7, safety Patie#ty_2TimTh, Kernel Calls, SyncSemPost (64) Enter, sync_ptr 0x1e3b814a7c count 0 owner 0xfffffffc
698693, 615ms 183us, 0x26575A3DE, 7, safety Patie#ty_2TimTh, Kernel Calls, SyncSemPost Exit, ret_val 0x0
699423, 615ms 763us, 0x26591DC0B, 7, safety Patie#ty_2TimTh, System, IPI (64), ipicmd 0x20 CHECK_INTR ipi 0x257f7810ed tid 34 pid 9424945 process safety
699451, 615ms 786us, 0x26592FE48, 7, safety Patie#ty_2TimTh, Process and Thread, Running, policy_name FIFO pid 9424945 tid 34 priority 255 policy 1 partition 7 sched_flags 0
699846, 616ms 99us, 0x265A23AE1, 7, safety Patie#ty_2TimTh, Kernel Calls, MsgReceivePulsev (64) Enter, chid 0x9 rparts 1
```

From the attachment, we found this thread is always running(**yellow bar**) and there are many Control events, such as.

```
696454, 613ms 446us, 0x265210A7F, 1, , Control Events, Buffer, sequence_number 6216609 event_count 0
696455, 613ms 447us, 0x2652112FE, 1, , Control Events, Time, msb 0x174d lsb 0x652112fe
696459, 613ms 451us, 0x265214063, 9, , Control Events, Time, msb 0x174d lsb 0x65214063
```

So why is this thread with **highest priority** running so long? Is it because **tracelogger** is running or **aps** partition has exceed 20% and kernel limits this thread's running time?
Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't know about QNX. But according to the documentation of tracelogger, it uses instrumented code to analyze the performance. In general instrumented code runs slower, because it will have to log events.
What exactly do you want to measure? How many times per second pulses can be received? Perhaps you can measure this without tracelogger? For example, add an extra variable and count the number of pulses and log this count somewhere. Do not log every count, but once per (say) 1 million, for otherwise logging the counts slows down the loop too much.

Comment: We use tracelogger to analyze whether the current system is strictly real time and found this tricky issue.